# Why is node-expat not installing on windows?

Tags: windows, npm, node-expat

As a final resort I hope that someone here can help me. I've been trying to install node-expat but no luck. 
I have installed from a packagemanager before, but when it installs from source I get the following errors:

```
..\..\..\deps\libexpat\lib\xmltok.c(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory [c:\dev\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\expat.vcxproj]
..\..\..\deps\libexpat\lib\xmlparse.c(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory [c:\dev\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\expat.vcxproj]
..\..\..\deps\libexpat\lib\xmlrole.c(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory [c:\dev\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\expat.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\windows.h(160): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory (C:\Users\currentuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.c) [c:\dev\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\expat.vcxproj]
```

Thank you in advance!